# Scale data for Hoeffding inequality

Tags: confidence-interval

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be independent random variables each bounded by the interval $[a,b]$. Using Hoeffding's inequality, the sample size required for a $(1-\alpha)$ confidence interval $E[\bar{X}]\pm t$ is $n\le\frac{(b-a)^2\log(2/\alpha)}{2t^2}$. Can you scale the initial distribution (e.g. divide each value in the distribution by $b$) so that the required sample size for the confidence interval is smaller?

Answer (score 0):

The bound you show scales with $(b-a)^2 /t^2$ so rescaling the data cannot help.

More precisely, if you divide all your data by e.g. $10^{-6}$ you will need $10^{-12}$ less sample to reach the very same $t$, but this t is now huge compared to the data (so you have a very low precision).

You have three parameters: the sample size $n$, the precision $t$, the confidence $\alpha$. You can tweak these three parameters as you want (or as you are constrained) but after that there is no free lunch. If you have a limited number of sample $n$, you will have to take easy on either the confidence or the precision. You cannot create information out of nowhere by tricks.

Note that Hoeffding bounds are reasonably tight but you can (sometimes) have sharper results if you know the family of distribution you are sampling from (e.g. Bernoulli).